# $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 2x+y \leq 2, x-y >4 \}$ open, closed or neither?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

This is a past paper question I am analyzing:

> In the following examples determine whether the given subsets are open, closed, or neither open nor closed
>
> - $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 2x+y \leq 2, x-y >4 \}$
> - $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x + y -z \leq 1 , x^2-y^2 +z^2 \geq 5 \}$
> - $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^2 -y^2 -z^2 < 0 \}$

I believe I know the answer for each of these but I want to correctly justify my reasoning.

I believe:
1. Neither
2. Closed 
3. Open

For the first, can I justify that is it not open because there is a point on the line $2x+y \leq 2$ for which the open ball is not contained entirely within the set? It is also not closed because the complement of this set is not open? Is this too vague?

I'm not sure the most efficient way to answer these and want to check I completely understand the logic.

Could anyone supply clear solutions to analyze?

Comment: A practical hint: weak inequalities give us colsed sets while the osrong ones indicate open sets. In all cases we have intersections. Then 2 is closed, 3 is open, 1 neither.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Robert show case (1) so I won't prove this one

I'll start with Case 3:

I can construct the following sequence: $a_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n)=\left(x_n,x_n+\frac1{n^2},0\right)$

Because $x_n-y_n-z_n=-\frac1{n^2}$ we have $a_n\in\text{case 3}$

Using the following property:

> A subset $A$ of a metric space(in this case $\Bbb R^3$) is closed iff(if and only if) whenever $(a_n)$ is a sequence of elements of $A$ then if $a_n\to a$ we have $a\in A$

We can take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity and we will get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_n,x_n+\frac1{n^2},0\right)=\left(x_n,x_n,0\right)\notin\text{case 3}$ hence it is an open set

Can you now do case 2?

Answer (score 0):

(1) is not open because $(x,y)$ satisfying $2x+y = 2$ and $x-y > 4$ (e.g. $(3,-4)$) is in the set but no open ball around it is contained in the set.

(1) is not closed because $(x,y)$ satisfying $2x+y \le 2$ and $x-y = 4$ (e.g. $(2,-2)$) is not in the set but any open ball around it intersects the set.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thank you! How would you justify that (2) is closed and (3) is open?